# WebView en un fragment Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-drawerlayout

estoy tratando de mostrar una pagina web en un contenedor web, WebView, ya lo he hecho pero en un activity normal, ahora quiero hacerlo pero en un fragment, ya que estoy utilizando un Navigation Drawer. anteriormente tenía el siguiente código el cual me funcionaba bien.

```
    String url="http://www.uniagustiniana.edu.co/";
    WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView01);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
```

Ahora quiero saber como usarlo pero en un fragment. muchas gracias;

Comment: Es similar, únicamente cambia el contexto, en lugar de this, usa getActivity() para obtener la activity que contiene el Fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El modo de cargar una url en un `WebView` en un `Fragment` o una `Activity` es idéntico, pero **en lugar de `this` usa `getActivity()` para obtener el contexto de la Activity que contiene el `Fragment`**, este es un ejemplo de como realizarlo:

Tenemos un layout `fragment_layout.xml` el cual contiene un `WebView` con id `webView01`:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container);


         String url="http://www.uniagustiniana.edu.co/";
         WebView view=(WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webView01);
         view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         view.loadUrl(url);


        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Hola me genera error en la linea: String url="http://www.uniagustiniana.edu.co/";

Comment: Error:(32, 16) error: unreachable statement
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_portal, container, false);

        String url="http://www.uniagustiniana.edu.co/";
        WebView view=(WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.wv_portal);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return view;
    }

Comment: @Alfredo ese error que marca es de compilación, realiza un "Build > clean project" y trata nuevamente, revisa si encuentras otro error.

Comment: Ya realicé el build > clean project y continua con el mismo error, un tutorial muestra que hay que reorganizarlo pero tambien seguí los pasos y continúa el mismo error. :/

Comment: Ahora me sale este error:   Error:(34, 17) error: variable view is already defined in method onCreateView(LayoutInflater,ViewGroup,Bundle)

Comment: @Alfredo elimina la primera linea.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Ayuda: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.tecnologias.uniagustiniana, PID: 4291
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference

Comment: at com.tecnologias.uniagustiniana.prueba.onCreateView(prueba.java:30)

Comment: ahhh el problema es que getSettings()  se esta llamando en una instancia nulla de WebView! @Alfredo Si estas realizando esto :  WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView01); , asegura que en el Layout se encuentre el elemento con el id webView01

Comment: Si se encuentra, es el contenedor web donde se va a cargar la página, he estado modificandolo por días y nada; le he cambiado de nombre al id del webView, he creado un nuevo layout, pero el id está bien. arroja mas detalles en el monitor.

Comment: @Alfredo agrega pro favor  todo tu método onCreate() y agrega el layout que se carga mediante setContentView( ? )

Comment: Hola @Jorge, mira que ahora me esta cargando por fin, pero quisiera pedirte que talvez me indiques si está bien de esta manera, aunque ya muestra la página. he usado el método onActivityCreated(); quedó de la siguiente manera:

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_portal, container, false);

    }

Comment: @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        String url="http://www.uniagustiniana.edu.co/";
        WebView view=(WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.wv1);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        //return void;
    }

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear una clase para el fragmento donde tendras el webview. Te dejo un ejemplo que he probado a ver si te sirve.

WebviewFragment.java:

```
public class WebviewFragment extends Fragment {
    WebView webView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout,container);
        webView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://es.stackoverflow.com/");
        return view;
    }

}
```

fragment_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebviewFragment fragment;
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragment = (WebviewFragment) 
        fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);

    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jose Luis Montañes, no he podido hacerlo, estoy trabajando con un Navigation Drawer, en el MainActivity esta todo el código para el menú desplegable, como sería posible que la url quedara de una vez en la clase WebviewFragment.java; por favor, gracias.

Comment: He modificado el WebViewFragment.java para que no tengas que pasarle la url, ya es editarla y ese webview cargara siempre esa pagina al crearlo. Con respecto al navigation drawer, solo tienes que llamar al fragment manager y reemplazar el contenido de tu activity por el fragment.